# How to save all items listed on listbox with my.settings

Tags: vb.net

I Try to save all the items from a list box with MY.SETTINGS 
And Retrieved again on load
But it seems i made an error but i cannot figure out what.

its give 2 error

This is the errors

Error   3   'itemmd5' is not a member of 'MediaAdsAntivirus.My.MySettings'.

Error   2   'myitems' is not a member of 'MediaAdsAntivirus.My.MySettings'.

For this errors i just figure out i forgot to add it on settings

but now i just have a new error 
This Is My New Error
Error   2   Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'.

And i need to load them on loadfrom
How Can I List All Items Again In To It

This Is My Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net


Public Class form15
Dim md5hashindexer = 1
Dim md5namesave = "Hashes"

#Region "Atalhos para o principal hash_generator função"


Function md5_hash(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("md5", file_name)

End Function

Function sha_1(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("sha1", file_name)

End Function

Function sha_256(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("sha256", file_name)

End Function

#End Region


Function hash_generator(ByVal hash_type As String, ByVal file_name As String)


    Dim hash
    If hash_type.ToLower = "md5" Then

        hash = MD5.Create
    ElseIf hash_type.ToLower = "sha1" Then

        hash = SHA1.Create()
    ElseIf hash_type.ToLower = "sha256" Then

        hash = SHA256.Create()
    Else
        MsgBox("Type de hash inconnu : " & hash_type, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return False
    End If


    Dim hashValue() As Byte


    Dim fileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(file_name)

    fileStream.Position = 0

    hashValue = hash.ComputeHash(fileStream)

    Dim hash_hex = PrintByteArray(hashValue)


    fileStream.Close()


    Return hash_hex

End Function


Public Function PrintByteArray(ByVal array() As Byte)

    Dim hex_value As String = ""


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To array.Length - 1


        hex_value += array(i).ToString("X2")

    Next i


    Return hex_value.ToLower

End Function


Private Sub BT_Parcourir_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BT_Parcourir.Click


    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        TB_path.Text = path


        LB_md5.Text = md5_hash(path)
        LB_sha1.Text = sha_1(path)
        LB_sha256.Text = sha_256(path)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(LB_md5.Text)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
        Dim itemmd5 = LB_sha256.Text
        Dim itemname = md5namesave + md5hashindexer
        For Each line As String In ListBox1.Items
            itemmd5 = My.Settings.myitems
            My.Settings.itemmd5 = ListBox1.Items

        Next
    End If



End Sub


Private Sub LB_sha256_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LB_sha256.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub form15_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally decide to save in txt file and load The data again from it
This Is The Working Code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net


Public Class form15
Dim md5hashindexer = 1


#Region "Atalhos para o principal hash_generator função"


Function md5_hash(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("md5", file_name)

End Function

Function sha_1(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("sha1", file_name)

End Function

Function sha_256(ByVal file_name As String)

    Return hash_generator("sha256", file_name)

End Function

#End Region


Function hash_generator(ByVal hash_type As String, ByVal file_name As String)


    Dim hash
    If hash_type.ToLower = "md5" Then

        hash = MD5.Create
    ElseIf hash_type.ToLower = "sha1" Then

        hash = SHA1.Create()
    ElseIf hash_type.ToLower = "sha256" Then

        hash = SHA256.Create()
    Else
        MsgBox("Type de hash inconnu : " & hash_type, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return False
    End If


    Dim hashValue() As Byte


    Dim fileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(file_name)

    fileStream.Position = 0

    hashValue = hash.ComputeHash(fileStream)

    Dim hash_hex = PrintByteArray(hashValue)


    fileStream.Close()


    Return hash_hex

End Function


Public Function PrintByteArray(ByVal array() As Byte)

    Dim hex_value As String = ""


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To array.Length - 1


        hex_value += array(i).ToString("X2")

    Next i


    Return hex_value.ToLower

End Function


Private Sub BT_Parcourir_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BT_Parcourir.Click


    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        TB_path.Text = path


        LB_md5.Text = md5_hash(path)
        LB_sha1.Text = sha_1(path)
        LB_sha256.Text = sha_256(path)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(LB_md5.Text)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
        Dim itemmd5 = LB_sha256.Text

        'For Each line As String In ListBox1.Items

        'My.Settings.itemsmd5 = itemmd5
        'md5hashindexer += 1
        'Next
    End If


    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
        sb.AppendLine(o)
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\checkedfilesmd5.txt", sb.ToString())


End Sub


Private Sub LB_sha256_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LB_sha256.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub form15_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\checkedfilesmd5.txt")
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
        sb.AppendLine(o)
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\checkedfilesmd5.txt", sb.ToString())
    MsgBox("Dados Guardados")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\checkedfilesmd5.txt")
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Label7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label7.Click
    MsgBox("Atençao Voce Vai Apagar Todos Os Dados Ja Escaneados")
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    System.IO.File.Delete("c:\checkedfilesmd5.txt")
End Sub
End Class
```